# Something is wrong with MinGW installing on the Win7 platform

Tags: mingw

I have installed the latest MinGW, but when I set MinGW Environment Variables.

[HowTo:_Install_MSYS_and_MinGW](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/HowTo%3a_Install_MSYS_and_MinGW_for_use_with_Eclipse_CDT)
They say:

```
"CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH"="C:\\MinGW\\include\\c++\\3.4.5;C:\\MinGW\\include\\c++\\3.4.5\\backward;C:\\MinGW\\include\\c++\\3.4.5\\mingw32;C:\\MinGW\\include" .
```

But in my “include” folder， there is no c++ folder？？？？
who can help me？thank you very much！！！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow !

If you have the latest minGW the PATH should look like:

```
C:/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++
```

**Eclipse -- Project -- Properties**

[image]

The Image shows `t:/` Replace `t:/`with `c:/`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using installer from this site: http://nuwen.net/mingw.html
It contains MinGW with the newest GCC, Boost, SDL, Git and more. It's very easy to install and you actually have nothing to do during the installation. Works perfect for me.

Greetings,